# Why is the firmware of the "Xbox Wireless Controller" not updated automatically?

Tags: controllers, xbox

I have now updated all Xbox Wireless Controllers (the first time since years). I didn't know that I had to do this regularly. Is there a reason why this is not done automatically? Updates to games and consoles also happen automatically. Most gamers will probably never update the controller firmware because they don't know about it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an assumption, but one possible reason controllers aren't updated in the background is because there really isn't a time controllers *could* be updated without you noticing. **Controllers can't update while you're using them, and they won't be connected to your console if they aren't in
use.**

When your console is in use, games can update in the background as long as they aren't actively being played. So if you are playing Far Cry, the system can update *Halo* in the background. However, your controller is almost always going to be in active use as long as your system is turned on.

When your console isn't in use, your Xbox can [download updates](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/power/learn-about-power-modes) while in sleep mode. This is how it can auto-install system updates. However, wireless controllers turn themselves off when not in use in order to save battery. The controller likely won't be reconnected until you plan on using it again.

It could also be that controller updates are considered lower priority than game and system updates. Compared to system or game updates, controller updates aren't released as often and don't add as many new features the average consumer would notice.